# Using the items in the list as the name for empty pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list as below

list = ['df1','df2','df3']

I want to create empty dataframes with these list items and I have tried the below

```
for i in list:
    str(i) = pd.DataFrame()
```

I would like to get 3 pandas dataframe created

```
df1
df2
df3
```

I have done an extensive search but not able to find a solution.

Comment: can the make the question some more clear, by showing your desired output

Comment: Basically, I want to create 3 empty pandas data frame whose name will be the same as the item names of the list

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: `str(i) = pd.DataFrame()` - what are you doing there - how can you equate  a string to a dataframe ?

Comment: the items in your list [df1,df2, df3] - is it a list of strings or is it a list of dataframes ?

Comment: its a list of strings , edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `exec` function:

```
l = ['df1','df2','df3']
for x in l:
    exec('%s = pd.DataFrame()' %x)
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I have space in the list item?  l = ['df 1','df 2','df 3']
Wondering if this will work

Comment: @MosesSoleman you cannot have a space. `exec` just excites python code and you cannot set a variable that has a space

Comment: Yeah, understood. sorry I didn't think about that part. I will replace the space with _

Comment: No need to apologize. Good luck!